# Issue with Sorting and Grouping List Items by Date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sorting, date

I'm working on a web application where I need to sort and group a list of items based on their dates. I have a list of checkboxes with associated date labels. I want to sort these checkboxes based on their associated dates and group them by month. Here's my HTML structure:

```
<ul class="faceted-filter-group-display__list">
    <li class="faceted-filter-group-display__list-item">
      <label class="faceted-filter-group-display__list-item-label">
        <input class="faceted-filter-group-display__list-item-input" type="checkbox" value="Monday, April 10th" />
        <svg class="faceted-filter-group-display__checkmark" width="14" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
          <path class="faceted-filter-group-display__checkmark-check" fill="none" d="M2.5 7L5.5 10L11.5 4"></path>
        </svg>
        <span class="faceted-filter-group-display__list-item-label-text">Monday, April 10th</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <!-- Other list items ... -->
  </ul>
```

I've tried implementing a sorting mechanism using JavaScript, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. I've included the full JavaScript code below:

```
function sortLiElements() {
    console.log("Sorting li elements...");
    const list = document.querySelector(".faceted-filter-group-display__list");
    const liElements = Array.from(
        list.querySelectorAll(".faceted-filter-group-display__list-item")
    );

    liElements.sort((a, b) => {
        const aText = a.querySelector(
            ".faceted-filter-group-display__list-item-label-text"
        ).textContent;
        const bText = b.querySelector(
            ".faceted-filter-group-display__list-item-label-text"
        ).textContent;
        const aDate = new Date(aText.split(", ")[1]);
        const bDate = new Date(bText.split(", ")[1]);
        return aDate - bDate;
    });

    for (const li of liElements) {
        list.appendChild(li);
    }
    console.log("Sorting complete.");
}

console.log("Starting sorting process...");
sortLiElements();
console.log("Sorting process finished.");

const ul = document.querySelector(".faceted-filter-group-display__list");
const liElements = Array.from(
    ul.querySelectorAll(".faceted-filter-group-display__list-item")
);

console.log("Creating month collections...");
const monthCollections = {
    January: [],
    February: [],
    March: [],
    April: [],
    May: [],
    June: [],
    July: [],
    August: [],
    September: [],
    October: [],
    November: [],
    December: [],
};

liElements.forEach((li) => {
    const dateText = li.querySelector(
        ".faceted-filter-group-display__list-item-label-text"
    ).textContent;
    const month = dateText.split(" ")[1]; // Get the month name
    monthCollections[month].push(li);
});

console.log("Sorting dates within month collections...");
for (const month in monthCollections) {
    monthCollections[month].sort((a, b) => {
        const dateTextA = a.querySelector(
            ".faceted-filter-group-display__list-item-label-text"
        ).textContent;
        const dateTextB = b.querySelector(
            ".faceted-filter-group-display__list-item-label-text"
        ).textContent;

        const dateValueA = new Date(dateTextA.split(" ").slice(1).join(" "));
        const dateValueB = new Date(dateTextB.split(" ").slice(1).join(" "));

        if (dateValueA.getDate() !== dateValueB.getDate()) {
            return dateValueA.getDate() - dateValueB.getDate();
        } else {
            return dateValueA - dateValueB;
        }
    });
    console.log(`${month}: ${monthCollections[month].length} items`);
}

console.log("Clearing and re-appending sorted elements...");
ul.innerHTML = "";
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (const month in monthCollections) {
    monthCollections[month].forEach((li) => fragment.appendChild(li));
}
ul.appendChild(fragment);
console.log("Re-appending complete.");
```

The desired outcome is to sort the checkboxes in ascending order by date and group them by month, while maintaining the initial structure of the Expected Output:

The expected output should be a list of checkboxes that are sorted by date and grouped by month, with the correct checkboxes under each respective month.

**What I've Tried:**

I've attempted to implement the sorting and grouping logic using the provided JavaScript code, but it's not producing the desired output. The sorting seems to work for the initial part, but the grouping part doesn't seem to function correctly.

**Additional Information:**

The date format used in the checkboxes is like "Monday, April 10th".
I can't directly add data attributes to the HTML due to the structure of the web application.
I've provided comments in the JavaScript code to explain what each part is intended to do.
Could someone please review my JavaScript code and provide guidance on how to properly sort and group the checkboxes by date and month?

**Thank you in advance for your help!HTML list.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified a few points in your script. Maybe this can be a starting point for you? At present I am a little unsure about the purpose of your `monthCollections` and what exactly you mean by "grouping" your `li`s by months. In my snippet I have plainly sorted all the `li` elements by absolute date. The grouping can be achieved by adding a month-headline into the `ul` each time a new month is encountered.

```js
const list=document.querySelector(".faceted-filter-group-display__list");
function appendLi(date){ // utility function for generating HTML markup ...
 const ds=date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", {weekday:"long", month:"long", day:"numeric"})
    +(["st","nd","rd"][date.getDate()-1]??"th");
 list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
 `<li class="faceted-filter-group-display__list-item">
   <label class="faceted-filter-group-display__list-item-label">
   <input class="faceted-filter-group-display__list-item-input" type="checkbox" value="${ds}" />
   <svg class="faceted-filter-group-display__checkmark" width="14" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
        <path class="faceted-filter-group-display__checkmark-check" fill="none" stroke="red" d="M2.5 7L5.5 10L11.5 4"></path>
   </svg>
   <span class="faceted-filter-group-display__list-item-label-text">${ds}</span>
   </label>
  </li>`)
}
function str2date(s){
 const [_,mon,day]=s.slice(0,-2).split(/,? /)
 return [new Date(`${day} ${mon} 2023`), mon];
}

function sortLiElements() {
    // console.log("Sorting li elements...");
    const liElements = [...list.querySelectorAll(".faceted-filter-group-display__list-item")];
    liElements.forEach(el=>{
      [el.date,el.mon]=str2date(el.querySelector(".faceted-filter-group-display__list-item-label-text"
        ).textContent);
    });

    liElements.sort((a, b) => a.date-b.date);
    list.innerHTML=""; // first empty the UL
    for (const li of liElements) {
        if (liElements.prev!=li.mon) {
          list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",`<h3>${li.mon}</h3>`);
          liElements.prev=li.mon
        }
        list.appendChild(li);
    }
    // console.log("Sorting complete.");
}
// create the initial HTML by adding LIs to UL:
[10,1,63,13,33,-61].forEach(d=>appendLi(new Date(2023,3,d)));

document.querySelector("button").onclick=sortLiElements;
```

```html
<ul class="faceted-filter-group-display__list">
    <!-- Other list items ... -->
</ul>
<button>sort</button>
```

I have created a utility function to simplify the sorting task:

```
function str2date(s){
 const [_,mon,day]=s.slice(0,-2).split(/,? /)
 return [new Date(`${day} ${mon} 2023`), mon];
}
```

The function re-creates a date object from the date string your are using in your page and at the end it returns an array with two elements:

1. the date object
2. the month name as received from the date string

I apply this function to create a `.date` and a `.mon` property in each element of my `liElements` array prior to the actual sorting. This makes the sorting and grouping simpler and faster.